# Published script as WebApp fails, but the test link works OK

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to publish a Google Apps Script form, built with UiApp.

So far, I have authorized and succesfully published the script as a web app.

After succesful deployment confirmation, the script editor is proposing a certain URL (Current web app URL). Below, this URL, the confirmation pop-up gives an HTML link that says :

"Test web app for your latest code".

If I click this test link while I'm logged-in to Google Drive, I can use the application perfectly, everything works fine.  However, if I try the real publish link, even while I'm logged-in to Google Drive,  the application fails:

Several panels that should be hidden appear visible,  and whenever a server callback should be fired, I get a message similar to this:

Error encountered: unknown macro 'nameOfHandler'

Am I missing something?  Any pointers?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish a new version from the File > Manage Versions menu and then redeploy the webapp with that new version chosen. The test link is always the most recent code, but the webapp doesn't change until you make a new version this way, so that you can test without accidentally breaking the current script.

Comment: Thank you @CoreyG, tried your solution, now it's working as expected  =)